# How can I refer to a configuration value in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

Given a Symfony2 configuration:

```
$treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
$rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('acme');        

$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->scalarNode('tempFolder')
            ->isRequired()
            ->cannotBeEmpty()
        ->end()
        ->scalarNode('logFile')
        ->end()
    ->end()
;
```

How can I make `logFile` depend on `tempFolder` so that it's like

```
tempFolder + '/' + logFile
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it has nothing to deal with configuration. Configuration in symfony is *almost* just validating. What would you need to **validate** ?

This looks like a job for your extension.

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $logRealpath = sprintf("%s/%s",
        rtrim($config['tempFolder'], '/'), 
        ltrim($config['logFile'], '/')
    );
    $container->setParameter('acme.log_realpath', $logRealpath);
}
```

Then you can just access it with

```
%acme.log_realpath%
```